# How to use controller in AngularJs directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that i want to use in my directive, how can i use controller for directive i want to access all controller functions in directive ?

directive.js

```
angular.module('App').directive('deleteButtons', function (prcDeleteFactory,$rootScope) {
  'use strict';
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
    id: '=ids',
    name: '@'
    },
    templateUrl:'scripts/common/prcDeleteDirective.html',
   link:function(scope){
     scope.deleteButton = function(){
       if(scope.name === 'process') {
         prcDeleteFactory.deleteObj(scope.name,scope.id);
         $rootScope.$broadcast('event');
       } else if(scope.name === 'risk') {
         prcDeleteFactory.deleteObj(scope.name,scope.id);
       } else if(scope.name === 'control'){
         prcDeleteFactory.deleteObj(scope.name,scope.id);
       }
     }
   }     
  }

});
```

Ctrl.js

```
angular.module('App').controller('ProcessCtrl', function($scope) {
                    'use strict';
                    $scope.confirmationWin = function(){
                    console.log('Print value');
                    };
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a controller using an anonymous function or by passing the string of an existing controller function registered on the same module like below.

```
return {
      restrict:'E',
      controller : 'ProcessCtrl'
  };
```

As you're using an `isolated scope` for your directive, to access controller properties and methods, you had to define the `controller` explicitly.

In case you don't want to use an isolated scope, you can remove the `scope` property from your Directive Definition Object that you're returning., The default value is `false` which means your directive will share the same scope as the enclosing container's controller. You can set `scope : true` which means your directive will get a new scope which prototypically inherits all methods and properties from the enclosing controller.

For more details on directive scopes, you can refer to this [link](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/).

Answer (score 0):

in your directive you can use

```
controller : 'ProcessCtrl',
controllerAs: 'vm',
bindToController: true
```

and then access controller properties in your directive template with vm.confirmationWin for example

Comment: so with above code in question just add properties as you mentioned you shoudl work , how about link function , do i still need it ?